# Why do we share rep on beta and here on meta?

Tags: support, reputation

I noticed both the design beta and meta sites share the same rep. SO and the corresponding meta separate the rep between each site. Why is it different here?

Note: this isn't meant to discuss which way is better, just curious as to why the change.

Comment: Just to be clear: MSO is the *exception* not the rule. On meta sites, users can't make bounties or earn reputation because making an excellent point in a discussion about a feature-request isn't equivalent to providing an excellent answer on the front page about (for example) image layout theory.

Answer (score 1):

Meta.SO currently serves as the Meta for the entire network and is treated as its own site.  All the rest of the sites share rep between Meta/Main.

See this answer as well:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128546/157384

Comment: I looked for this over there. I guess I wasn't searching for the right phrases or terms. Thanks.